# open new window with JS - but with MEDIA_URL inside - HOW?

Tags: javascript, python, django, onclick

i am trying to open a new window when the user clicks the file download link. but the file should come from my media folder, which is uploaded by the user. how is it possible to embed django template code into js? this is my vision:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('{{MEDIA_URL}}','mywindow','width=720,height=900')">download here</a>
```

is it ever possible?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, why not? Make sure the JavaScript in question is serve through Django's template system, of course.

You should use the escapejs filter on template variables in JavaScript strings though. As in:

```
"{{ MEDIA_URL|escapejs }}"
```

Comment: ``<a href="#" onclick="window.open('{{MEDIA_URL|escapejs}}/file',..`` like this?